# How to calculate time of birth for annual prediction

Tags: astrology

How can i calculate time of birth for annual prediction report at [Local Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time)?

Comment: What's the actual time of birth? GMT/IST??

Comment: What is L.M.T ?

Comment: Local Mean Time (LMT) is a type of solar time, a timekeeping method using the Sun's movements across the sky.

Comment: What's the actual time of birth? GMT/IST??  IST and in terms of GMT it is +5:30